# Starting weblogic results in ORA-01035: ORACLE only available to users with RESTRICTED SESSION privilege

Tags: oracle, weblogic

so i tried restarting weblogic server and restart failed with error ORA-01035: ORACLE only available to users with RESTRICTED SESSION privilege. i granted restricted session to the db user but still getting the same error.

Comment: Instead of why this user cannot connect, I would be more concerned about why the database is started in restricted mode.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

i) Check with the Database Administrator and disable the restricted mode. Steps may vary according to the database.

alter system disable restricted session;
ii) Verify that the login is allowed.

select logins from v$instance;

### LOGINS

ALLOWED

iii) Restart the Database.

iv) Restart the AdminServer.

Option 2:

Contact the Database Administrator to grant RESTRICTED SESSION privileges for all the required DB users.